# Mouse permanently stuck on left side of screen

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

One of my two monitors is died, so while my computer was turned off I unplugged the dead monitor then turned my computer back on. When I got to the log in page I typed my password and got to the desktop my mouse was stuck to the left edge of the screen. I can move it up and down, and left and right click, but it won't come off the edge.

I tried switching the monitor cable to the other slot to see if that would make a difference but nothing changed. If it makes a difference, I'm using Kubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Your hint on monitors solved the problem for me.

I put the 2nd monitor I had back. I suppose that you have a problem with having two screens, I don't mean 2 physical monitors, but two defined screens in your `Xorg.conf` (probably in `/etc/Xorg/Xorg.conf`, I'm not on a Linux PC now).

Try and remove the sections pointing to your broken monitor or to you having two monitors.